# regex for picking up third line before a match

Tags: python, regex

I have raw data in this form:

```
Line I am interested in
Another line
Another line
Text I can identify
```

I'm interested in picking up the first line by using the fourth one. If I wanted the one right before I'd use `\n(.*)\nText I can identify`, but I don't know how to get that for two lines before.

Please help!

Comment: Why would it be any different?

Comment: Post two or three examples of the 4 lines of text clearly indicating which lines/text you want to capture.

Comment: See: https://regex101.com/r/iQH5Te/1  Unless you have a line above the "interested" one - you do need the leading `\n`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If your example works for the line before, then I guess `\n(.*)\n.*\n.*\nText I can identify` should work for 3 lines before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) of limited length and then it is easy to refer to some number of lines previous in an iterable:

```
import re 
from collections import deque 

d=deque(maxlen=5)

for line in your_file:
    d.append(line.strip())
    if re.search(r'identify', line): print(d[-4])
```

The deque `d` is limited to 5 lines in length so it is very memory friendly for large files.

If your date is in the form of a string, just split the text:

```
txt='''\
Line I am interested in
Another line
Another line
Text I can identify'''

import re 
from collections import deque 

d=deque(maxlen=5)

for line in txt.splitlines():
    d.append(line)
    if re.search(r'identify', line): print(d[-4])
```

Prints:

```
Line I am interested in
```